# Cannot browse HTTP to a load balanced VIP from w2k8 boxes, but can get to it from w2k3

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, load-balancing, nic

I have a strange problem and am looking for suggestions.

The environment:

several VLANs on the same switch, that all talk to each other via the ASA using hairpin routing:

VLAN 500 - Windows 2003 servers with single NIC each

VLAN 501 - Windows 2008 servers with multiple NICs each.

VLAN 502 - Barracuda LB340 load balancer and load-balanced VIPs for HTTP

VLAN 503 - Windows 2003 servers with single NIC each

I have VIPs on vlan 502 that are load balanced to servers on VLAN 501. The NICs on VLAN 501 have metrics such that the NIC for network access has priority over the NIC for load balancing.

Everything works as expected from the outside world, and from servers in VLAN 500 and 503. In other words, I can browse `http://myvip1.site.com` from outside, and I will hit one of the backend servers. The same goes for a server in vlan 500 or 503, it works too.

The problem is that I'm unable to hit the VIP from a server in VLAN 501. telnet to port 80 on the VIP just times out.

ping works however. I'm able to ping all the VIPs, but not telnet to 80 on them.

At first I thought it was a firewall blocking access, or a misconfigured gateway, or some other type of networking misconfiguration, but at this point I've narrowed it down to the W2K8 boxes not being able to browse to these VIPs on port 80 (or any other port actually).
I should mention that browsing to the server directly (i.e. `http://server1/`) works, just not to the VIP.

I'm not sure what to look for. Is it a W2k8 network setting? Is it something in the NICs on my w2k8 servers? Is it the fact that they have multiple NICs? Why are they acting all strange but w2k3 boxes are fine?

Thanks for looking